# My userData return undefined react js fetch

Tags: reactjs, fetch

On my console log, i can see my object for my response.json but i think i forget something for my setUser because my object return undefined ?

```
function Profil() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  const getUser = () => {
    const headers = new Headers({
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
    });

    const options = {
      method: "GET",

      headers: headers,
    };

    fetch(
      "https://..../user",
      options
    )
      .then((response) => {
        return console.log(response.json());
      })
      .then(
        (responseObject) => {
          const userData = responseObject;

          setUser({ ...user, userData });

          console.log(user);
        },

        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Prénom</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Profil;
```

my object on my console log is

[[PromiseResult]]: Object
email: "test@gmail.com"
firstname: "test"
lastname: "test"
_id: "61519405b8dc4a001be666"

Comment: `return console.log(response.json());` returns `undefined`  Don't return a console.log(), just return `response.json()` or break it into 2.  Otherwise you aren't chaining what you think you're chaining.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning `undefined` from your Promise:

```
.then((response) => {
  return console.log(response.json());
})
```

`response.json()` itself returns a Promise, so return that:

```
.then((response) => {
  return response.json();
})
```

There's no need to log the Promise itself.  If you want to log the raw response JSON to the console then do that in the next Promise:

```
.then(
  (responseObject) => {
    // here:
    console.log(responseObject);

    const userData = responseObject;

    setUser({ ...user, userData });

    console.log(user);
  },

  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

---

Additionally, be aware of what this is doing:

```
console.log(user);
```

This will log the state of `user` *when this code is running*.  It will *not* reflect the update from here:

```
setUser({ ...user, userData });
```

Because that state update happens asynchronously.  If you want to log the updated state value, either do it in a `useEffect`, or directly in the rendering of the component, or just log the object you're passing to `setUser`.

You also don't need your `userData` variable at all.  It adds no value and is just a reference to `responseObject`.